# Browserify-shim using google as a dependency

Tags: javascript, google-maps, browserify, browserify-shim

I use a couple of libraries from google viz.

1. google-maps
2. google-picker
3. google client api for authentication

I would like to shim [L.Google](https://gist.github.com/crofty/2197042) using `browserify-shim`:

```
"browserify-shim": {
"google": "global:google",
"L.Google": {
  "depends": [
    "leaflet:L",
    "google"
  ]
}
...
}
```

I get this error:

```
 Error: Cannot find module 'google' from 'C:\Users\lenovo\Downloads\Browserify\Br
owserify\js\leaflet-plugins'
    at C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\
resolve\lib\async.js:46:17
    at process (C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\node
_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:173:43)
    at ondir (C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\node_m
odules\resolve\lib\async.js:188:17)
    at load (C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\node_mo
dules\resolve\lib\async.js:69:43)
    at onex (C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\node_mo
dules\resolve\lib\async.js:92:31)
    at C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\
resolve\lib\async.js:22:47
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)
```

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?

Comment: @Simon Yes, I have fixed it with webpack using the [issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/150) and the `expose-loader` . There are also npm packages called `google-client-api` and the `google-maps`. There are also prebuilt packages for react and angular if you are into that.